# direction of resultant moment about axis using scalar and right hand grip rule?

Tags: statics, moment

From the picture posted, this question is taken from my solution manual. I understand that using vector method of finding the resultant moment. I also know when we use scalar with right grip rule to determine the resultant moment, the answer must be the same as of that using the vector method. What i dun understand is the positive and negative sign when finding resultant moment about an axis using the scalar analysis. Like in the picture, the resultant moment about y axis, M R Ay, when i applied right hand grip rule, it should in the positive  y direction or +20.5Nm but it is otherwise in the solution manual. Any explanation would much appreciated.

[[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Point the thumb of your right hand placed at point $A$ in the $\hat j$ direction and your fingers will point upwards in the $\hat k$ direction.

So to get a positive torque about $A$ in the $\hat j$ direction you need to have a force in the $\hat k$ direction.

In your example the component of the force in the $\hat k$ direction is negative and so the torque about $A$ in the $\hat j$ direction is negative.

Comment: thank you. I realized i just see the direction of the force in a completely wrong sense...or opposite sense since it is about point A